# Adding a className dynamically in React.js with Tailwind.css

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css

Let's say I have a React component that gets the Tailwind class name from `props`
for example :

```
import React from "react";

export default function Header({navColor}) {

  return (
    <nav
    className="flex justify-center items-center text-white  text-xl h-14"> //I want to add a class that it's name is the (navColor) value to the nav tag 
      TEST
    </nav>
  );
}
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: This npm package is better for that purpose =>  https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Comment: Thank you, what are the benefits of using this library over Template literals?

Comment: It abstract out all the possible ways to set class name dynamically with different conditions into a single function. You can reuse it everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to achieve that

Use `${}` inside **backticks** **``**

```
<nav
    className={`flex justify-center items-center text-white  text-xl h-14 ${navColor}`}> 
      TEST
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import classNames from "classnames";
import React from "react";

export default function Header({ navColor }) {
  const headerClass = classNames(
    "flex justify-center items-center text-white text-xl h-14",
    navColor,
  );
  return <nav className={headerClass}>TEST</nav>;
}
```

[classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) is also one of good option. You don't have to worry about misadding whitespace.

Comment: Not much need for `classnames` dependency when we can use template literals as above answer.

Comment: @CodeFinity Penguin's point is, not worrying about whitespaces. That's a big headache. Thats what classnames is solving. Not every dependency is heavy. Its a minimalistic function https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames/blob/main/index.js Thats all